# java.lang.SecurityException when JMX monitor Tomcat from JConsole

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, jconsole

The scenario is simple. I'm trying to monitor from my local workstation *(Mac OS 10.9)* a remote server *(Ubuntu 12.04)* that's running *Tomcat 7.0.54* where my *Spring Java* app is deployed.

*JVM hotspot 64bit "1.7.0_51"* is used in both server and workstation.

### THE STEPS

1. Configure Tomcat's JmxRemoteLifecycleListener to fix ports (server.xml)

   ```
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener"
     rmiRegistryPortPlatform="9940" rmiServerPortPlatform="9941" />
   ```
2. Copy **catalina-jmx-remote.jar** into CATALINA_HOME/lib
3. Open ports
       sudo iptables -L

   ```
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9940
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9941
   ```
4. setenv.sh

   ```
   IP=`ifconfig eth0  | grep 'inet '| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`;

   export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS
   -Dcom.sun.management.local.only=false 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true 
   -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$IP 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jmxremote.password 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jmxremote.access 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
   ```

   IP gets resolved to host's internal ip address, say 10.239.94.133.
5. Start Tomcat and check **netstat -nap | grep java**

   ```
   tcp6  0  0 :::9940 :::*  LISTEN      6538/java       
   tcp6  0  0 :::9941 :::*  LISTEN      6538/java
   ```

   Up to here it all seems to indicate the setup is correct. I can telnet my remote host to both ports and I can see Tomcat(6538) listening to those ports.
6. From my local host **jconsole -debug** and connect to remote process

   ```
    service:jmx:rmi://PUBLIC-IP:9941/jndi/rmi://PUBLIC-IP:9940/jmxrmi
   ```

### THE PROBLEM

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory RMI client socket factory in stub!
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.checkStub(RMIConnector.java:1881)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:295)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:370)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:292)
```

Is there anything I've missed? I'm running in circles with this :-/ Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> IP gets resolved to host's internal ip address, say 10.239.94.133.

That was the problem. The fix is actually to set

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=server.public.ip.address
```

You still get the same error in JConsole (with -debug option) but disregard it and click on 'insecure' button to continue and your are in :)